# OAuth1.0 Authentication Using Alamofire

Tags: swift3, alamofire, oauth-1.0a

I am using alamofire for networking in swift3.0 project. I need to get data from woocommerce rest apis e.g http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties
Below is the code I have added in my project. I think there is an authentication issue.

```
let params = ["oauth_consumer_key":consumerKey, "oauth_consumer_secret":consumerSecret, "oauth_timestamp":timeInterval, "oauth_nonce": nonce, "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_version": "1.0"] as [String : Any];

    Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }
```

Response:

```
{
    code = "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view";
    data =     {
        status = 401;
    };
    message = "Sorry, you cannot view this resource.";
}
```

Comment: After wasting approx 2-3 days I figured a solution and that is to add simple Php library which handle all the request by it self. Library : https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

I should have thought in this direction 2-3 days earlier!

Comment: P.S: The code posted in question is not a correct way to communicate oauth1 apis. I have tried many different ways to create oauth signature by base url (Method&URL&Parameter)  and consumer secrect and hashing them by SHA1. 
https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html

Comment: Do you have found a solution, except the library php ? Is it impossible to do it only with alamofire ? Cause i got the same problem...

Comment: I would not say its impossible but finding the solution for that and to know whether you are trying in right direction is difficult because of Outh1.0 conventional ways of authentication.

Comment: I agree, thank's for your response. I've found a solution, using OAuthSwiftAlamofire pod to sign my request.

Comment: Good to hear that. Can you post the solution with some details/code so other can benefit from it.thanks

Comment: I think this is really specific to me, but when i've the time i'll do it

Comment: Use https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwiftAlamofire this library. This solved my issue. You don't have to pass all those values. Just add consumer_secret and consumer_key using this library and it will work fine.